# Download image file from azure storage

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to synch image files there in azure storage(listing image thumb nile).

my Requirement:
Almost every android app has a need to load remote images. While loading remote images, we have to take care of below things:

Image loading process must be done in background (i.e. asynchronously) to avoid blocking UI main thread.
Image recycling image should be done.
Image should be displayed once its loaded successfully.
Images should be cached in local memory for the later use.
If remote image gets failed (due to network connection or bad url or any other reasons) to load then it should be managed perfectly for avoiding duplicate requests to load the same again, instead it should load if and only if net connection is available.
Memory management should be done efficiently.
In short, we have to write a code to manage each and every aspects of image loading but there are some awesome libraries available, using which we can load/download image asynchronously. We just have to call the load image method and success/failure callbacks and that what i want achieve with azure blob storage.

Asynchronous image loading
Consider a case where we are having 50 images and 50 titles and we try to load all the images/text into the listview, it won’t display anything until all the images get downloaded.

Here Asynchronous image loading process comes in picture. Asynchronous image loading is nothing but a loading process which happens in background so that it doesn’t block main UI thread and let user to play with other loaded data on the screen. Images will be getting displayed as and when it gets downloaded from background threads.

Comment: Have you seen [this sample for android?](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Samples/Android-MobileServices-Storage) It use [SAS](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) for accessing blobs. And basically accessing blobs with SAS token is no different than just constructing correct URL.